# Mongodb - expire subset of data in collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, cron

I am wondering what is the best way to expire only a subset of a collection.

In one collection I store conversion data and click data.
The click data I would like to store for lets a week
And the conversion data for a year.

In my collection "customers" I store something like:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53f5c0cfeXXXXXd"), "appid" : 2, **"action" : "conversion**", "uid" : "2_b2f5XXXXXX3ea3", "iid" : "2_2905040001", "t" : ISODate("2014-07-18T15:01:00.001Z") }
And
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53f5c0cfe4b0d9cd24847b7d"), "appid" : 2, **"action" : "view"**, "uid" : "2_b2f58679e6f73ea3", "iid" : "2_2905040001", "t" : ISODate("2014-07-18T15:01:00.001Z") }
for the click data

So should I exucute a ensureIndex or something like a cronjob?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use TTL indexes  in MongoDB

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of built in techniques you can use.  The most obvious is a [TTL collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) which will automatically remove documents based on a date/time field.  The caveat here is that for that convenience, you lose some control.  You will be automatically doing deletes all the time that you have no control over, and deletes are not free - they require a write lock, they need to be flushed to disk etc.  Basically you will want to test to see if your system can handle the level of deletes you will be doing and how it impacts your performance.

Another option is a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) - capped collections are pre-allocated on disk and don't grow (except for indexes), they don't have the same overheads as TTL deletes do (though again, not free).  If you have a consistent insert rate and document size, then you can work out how much space corresponds to the time frame you wish to keep data.  Perhaps 20GiB is 5 days, so to be safe you allocate 30GiB and make sure to monitor from time to time to make sure your data size has not changed.

After that you are into more manual options. For example, you could simply have a field that marks a document as expired or not, perhaps a boolean - that would mean that expiring a document would be an in-place update and about as efficient as you can get in terms of a MongoDB operation.  You could then do a batch delete of your expired documents at a quiet time for your system when the deletes and their effect on performance are less of a concern.

Another alternative: you could start writing to a new database every X days in a predictable pattern so that your application knows what the name of the current database is and can determine the names of the previous 2.  When you create your new database, you delete the one older than the previous two and essentially always just have 3 (sub in numbers as appropriate).  This sounds like a lot of work, but the benefit is that the removal of the old data is just a drop database command, which just unlinks/deletes the data files at the OS level and is far more efficient from an IO perspective than randomly removing documents from within a series of large files.  This model also allows for a very clean backup model - mongodump the old database, compress and archive, then drop etc.

As you can see, there are a lot of trade offs here - you can go for convenience, IO efficiency, database efficiency, or something in between - it all depends on what your requirements are and what fits best for your particular use case and system.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer. It answers all the methods and scenarios to do the `control and expire mongo DB data`. great! + 1